How to know when a SwiftUI View redraw has completed
My MacOS app uses SwiftData and SwiftUI to store and display recipes.  When I add a new recipe to my SwiftData model, my List of recipes updates.  At this point I want to programatically scroll to the new recipe by changing a State variable (selectedRecipe) and using the .onChange modifier to action a scrollTo() command.  But the scroll never happens, I believe because the List has not yet been updated.
I've tried this using a non-SwiftData model and it works fine, so I'm fairly sure that SwiftData has introduced a delay.  My question is, is there some way to know when the List update is complete, at which point I can safely use scrollTo()?
Here's my (simplified) code:
@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext

var recipes: [Recipe]
@State private var selectedRecipe: UUID?

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                Listself.recipies, id: \.id, selection: $selectedRecipe) { recipe in
                    RecipeCellView(recipe: recipe)
                }
                .focusable()
                .onAppear() {
                    if recipes.isEmpty == false {
                        self.selectedRecipe = recipes[0].id
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedRecipe) { (old, new) in
                    proxy.scrollTo(new, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button { self.addRecipe()
                } label: { Text("Add Recipe") }    
            }
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selectedRecipe = self.selectedRecipe {
            let recipe = self.searchResults.first {
                $0.id == selectedRecipe }
            if let toDisplay = recipe {
                RecipeTabView(recipe: toDisplay)
            }
        }
    }
}

func addRecipe() {
    let myRecipe = Recipe()
    modelContext.insert(myRecipe)
    
    self.selectedRecipe = myRecipe.id
}


self.recipes is just a plain var. Shouldn't this be a @Query?

The @Query happens before this View, and the recipes are passed as a var. Normal practice  - not the answer I’m afraid.

The primary reason is not that the view updates before the data is inserted. It won't scroll even if you add a delay before scrollTo.
The ID you passed to scrollTo, i.e. new is of type UUID?, but the views in the List presumably have UUID as their IDs. The types do not match, so it does not scroll.
You should unwrap new before using it.
if let new {
    proxy.scrollTo(new, anchor: .top)
}

Here is a fully working example:
@main
struct FooApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Recipe.self, inMemory: true)
    }
}

@Model
class Recipe {
    var name: String
    var id: UUID
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Query
    var recipes: [Recipe]
    
    var body: some View {
        AnotherView(recipes: recipes)
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext

    let recipes: [Recipe]
    @State private var selectedRecipe: Recipe.ID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            VStack {
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    List(self.recipes, selection: $selectedRecipe) { recipe in
                        Text(recipe.name)
                    }
                    .focusable()
                    .onChange(of: selectedRecipe) { (old, new) in
                        if let new {
                            proxy.scrollTo(new)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button { self.addRecipe()
                    } label: { Text("Add Recipe") }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selectedRecipe = self.selectedRecipe {
                Text(recipes.first(where: { $0.id == selectedRecipe })?.name ?? "")
            }
        }
    }

    func addRecipe() {
        let myRecipe = Recipe(name: UUID().uuidString)
        modelContext.insert(myRecipe)
        self.selectedRecipe = myRecipe.id
    }
}


There were actually two problems.  The one you identified wins the banana, but when I used it in my code, it still didn't work.  The other issue was that my RecipeCellView() took a Recipe? type as an argument, but I was giving it a Recipe.  Why this only caused an error in scrolling, I have no idea.  SwiftUI works (?) in mysterious ways.
